# javascript changing the value of a keyboard key

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textfield takes only letters, I want if I pressed (a) I get (b) and if I pressed (b) get (c)...etc, if I pressed (z) get alert("there is no letters after")

```
    <input type="number" id="example" onkeypress="return numbersKey(event)">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="text" id="example2" onkeypress="return lettersOnly(event)">
    <script>
        var myinput = document.getElementById('example'),
            myp = document.getElementById('demo');
        function numbersKey(evt) { 
      
            // Only ASCII charactar in that range allowed 

            var ASCIICode = event.keyCode;

            if (ASCIICode > 31 && (ASCIICode < 48 || ASCIICode > 57))

                return false;

            return true;
            
        };
            
        }
        function lettersOnly() 
        {
            // Only ASCII character in that range allowed
            var charCode = event.keyCode;

            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8){

                return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode + 1);
            }    
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this complete code and run it once to see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="example2" onkeypress="lettersOnly(event)">
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script>
    function lettersOnly(event) {
        var charCode = event.keyCode;
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8){
            if(charCode == 90 || charCode == 122){
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "There's no letter after";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode + 1);
            }

        }    
        else{
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Not Letter";
        }
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but still doesn't work..ask for more clarification.

Comment: @MohannedHendawy Show me your whole code, including html

Comment: @MohannedHendawy I updated my answer. CHeck it once